# request type SOAP and XML in datapower

Tags: xml, soap, ibm-datapower

This question might sound naïve and a stupid one, but because I don't have access to DataPower at the moment Please pardon me for this question.

My question is suppose I have SOAP request .
can I use my  'XML' request-Type in DataPower and give the SOAP request as input to DataPower.

Any link or help will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course since SOAP is XML. If you run it as SOAP (in a MPGW) though you will get some validation on the envelope and and service variables automatically...

Answer (score 1):

Yes :) , you can do it.

Let's see what the main difference is between these two and when to use them.

- **SOAP** request type implies that the service expects messages to adhere to SOAP protocol standards, including its specific structure and potentially additional WS-* standards.
  *on the other hand*
- **XML** request type implies that the service expects messages to be in XML format but does not enforce the strict message structure of SOAP. It primarily focuses on XML data validation against XML schemas.

The choice of request type depends on the requirements of the system and the nature of the traffic it needs to process.
**SOAP** is often used in web services where strict message structure and standardized protocols are required, while **XML** may be used when flexibility in message structure is allowed.